# Grow a Section of Section report by the content height

Tags: c#, vb.net, activereports, grapecity

I am trying to add content in the detail section of `ActiveReport`. But the section height is limited to 2 inches. It is taking only (2/0.2 = )10 items. I want the section to increase its height as the contents increase, so that it can adopt all item. It seems like `.CanGrow` is not working. The code I am using is as below.

```
Dim lObjSecRpt As New GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport()
Dim lObjLbl As New GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.Label()
Dim c As Single = 0.2F

Try

lObjSecRpt.Sections.InsertPageHF()
lObjSecRpt.Sections(0).BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
lObjSecRpt.Sections(0).Height = 0.0F

lObjSecRpt.Sections.Insert(1, New GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.Detail())
lObjSecRpt.Sections(1).BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
lObjSecRpt.Sections(1).CanGrow = True

For Each dr As DataRow In mObjDtReport.Rows
    lObjLbl = New GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.Label()

    lObjLbl.Alignment = GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Document.Section.TextAlignment.Left
    lObjLbl.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
    lObjLbl.Location = New PointF(0.0F, c)
    lObjLbl.Height = 0.2F
    lObjLbl.Width = 1.0F
    lObjLbl.Text = CStr(dr("RptObjNam"))
    lObjSecRpt.Sections(1).Controls.Add(lObjLbl)
    c += c
Next

Me.rptViewer.LoadDocument(lObjSecRpt)
```

Comment: [@Sankalp 1984](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1131867/sankalp1984) can you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ammar,

What you are trying to do in the code is creating sections and adding controls to the sections on the fly. So this is like creating a report layout at runtime. Since you are simply adding controls to the detail section, the format event for the detail section will not fire for each control as it is not bound to any data. Rather you are just adding controls to it. You can check and example of creating reports on the fly [here](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR8Help/AR8_HelpOnlineEN/arWLKRunTimeLayouts.html).

If you want that the detail section should grow to show all the added controls, then you will need to increment its height on the basis of the total height of the controls inside it. For example check the sample code below which demonstrates how this can be done. You can simply add this code to the Form_Load event to verify it.

```
    Dim lObjLbl As New GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.Label()
Dim c As Single = 0.2F
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim rpt As New GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport
    rpt.Sections.InsertPageHF()
    rpt.Sections(0).BackColor = Color.Yellow
    rpt.Sections(0).Height = 1.0F
    rpt.Sections.Insert(1, New GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.Detail())
    rpt.Sections(1).Name = "Detail"
    rpt.Sections("Detail").BackColor = Color.Gainsboro
    rpt.Sections("Detail").CanGrow = True

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 20
        Dim lObjLbl As New GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.Label()
        lObjLbl.Alignment = GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Document.Section.TextAlignment.Left
        lObjLbl.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
        lObjLbl.Location = New PointF(0.0F, c)
        lObjLbl.Size = New SizeF(1.0F, 0.2F)
        lObjLbl.Text = "Record: " + i.ToString()
        lObjLbl.BackColor = Color.Aqua
        rpt.Sections("Detail").Controls.Add(lObjLbl)
        c += 0.2
    Next
    Dim height As Double = 0
    For Each control As GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.ARControl In rpt.Sections("Detail").Controls
        height = height + control.Height
    Next
    rpt.Sections("Detail").Height = height
    Viewer1.LoadDocument(rpt)
End Sub
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Sankalp, your answer counts for me. But being a programmer there are number of workarounds and I have applied the one which is best for me. But my concern was "Is there any way an `ActiveReport` is providing to increase the height for its content". In my case location and size are not constant. More than one controls may lie in one line, so increasing the height for all controls is not a good idea.